Could you blind someone as part of a nonlethal attack when reducing an Enemy's health to zero?
Been wanting to try my hand at killing fewer enemies, but at the same time with how ubiquitous simple healing magic is for our faceless NPCs, I've been thinking of how to implement more permanent ways to disable opponents that isn't necessarily lethal, nor relies on complex magic to trap or bind them after defeating them. The simplest I can think of is just blinding them via an attack to the eyes or something. People can be blinded without dying, and I figured if it's done as part of an attack that knocks an opponent unconscious, it should be kosher, but I don't know how viable a strategy this is.
Obviously the main issue is that called shots aren't a thing in 5e. Barring some special class feature or a spell, just because I say I'm trying to blind someone doesn't necessarily mean I can, even if my attack lands. This is fair enough if the enemy is still at full HP: even if they take damage I obviously can't just add a debilitating status effect to the attack unless it's an actual feature. Just as well I can say I'm going to stab someone through the heart or cut off their heads, but all that doesn't really happen until the target's HP drops to zero.
But if I do manage to take them out, would this sort of physical, crippling disability be a viable thing a player can do to an enemy?

Can you clarify what you'd consider off limits? If you're willing to hurt and maim a target but not kill them, where's the line? Would you gouge the eyes out of an unconscious foe, break their limbs and cut their tendons? There are plenty of ways to inflict a long-term disability, but "dead" could also be considered a long-term disability, so knowing why that's not one you're willing to inflict would help.

Welcome to the peaky blinders

Could you please elaborate, what the goal is? What is the reason why you don't want to kill enemies, but are okay with crippling them (which probably leads to death anyway). Is it just a roleplay thing, or something related with the plot?

I'm not sure what kind of answer you want. Do you want to know if this is possible in the rules? Do you want to know if this is a good battle Strategy? Do you want to know if this is a balanced house rule?

Not sure what you're looking for?  Your question reads, "I want to do a called shot.  Called shots aren't a thing in 5e.  But can I do a called shot?"  Have you talked to your DM?

Tell us more about your game - are NPC's getting death saves (if not they are just dead, no potion helps), are you worried about revivication, etc.  Beyond seeming psychotic, this method would be used by everyone if it were available since being blinded is a debilitating condition in combat.

I'm voting to close right now because this question doesn't really seem to have a stated goal. You have a stated question on whether such a proposal is a 'viable thing' but the answer to that isn't going to be found in the rules and is very opinion based. I think a better question to ask would be to present a proposed house rule that achieves what you're looking for and ask the question what the impacts of the house rule are within the game as a whole.

@TigerGuy as far as I understand — the PC chooses to knock an NPC unconscious at 0 hp, but NPC's allies heal him and get him back to the fight.

You can work with your DM and adapt the optional rules from the DMG for Injuries.
The Dungeon Master Guide (pages 272-273) provides some guidelines for lingering injuries:

Damage normally leaves no lingering effects. This
option introduces the potential for long-term injuries. It's up to you to decide when to check for a lingering injury. A creature might sustain a lingering injury under the following circumstances:

When it takes a critical hit
When it drops to 0 hit points but isn't killed outright
When it fails a death saving throw by 5 or more

To determine the nature of the injury, roll on the Lingering Injuries table. This table assumes a typical humanoid physiology, but you can adapt the results for creatures with different body types.

The table (summarized below) is the following:



d20 roll
Injury




1
Lose an eye


2
Lose an Arm or a Hand


3
Lose a Foot or Leg


4
Limp


5-7
Internal Injury


8-10
Broken Ribs


11-13
Horrible Scar


14-16
Festering Wound


17-20
Minor Scar



In particular, Lose an Eye reports:

You have disadvantage on Wisdom (Perception) checks that rely on sight and on ranged attack rolls. Magic such as the regenerate spell can restore the lost eye. If you have no eyes
left after sustaining this injury, you're blinded.

You and your DM can work around this optional rules, for adapting them to NPCs and enemies, since these are a DM tool for injuries on the players' characters.

You have to put a full blank line in between text and the start of a table. Otherwise, the table will render in the preview, but not render after submission.

@ThomasMarkov Thanks Thomas! I did not check after posting, and I think it is the n+1-th time that I do this...

recommend adding the proviso that when these things get implemented, it's usually the players who deal with lingering injuries, not enemies, since most enemies end up dead.

@TigerGuy Yes, I address this in the last sentence: "You and your DM can work around this optional rules, for adapting them to NPCs". Maybe I can add "[...] to NPCs and enemies", to be more clear.
